# can't recover windows after windows 8 to 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, data-recovery, system-restore, system-recovery

I seem to not be able to recover my pc to its original win 8 condition (or win 10) after a win 10 upgrade then a win 10 recovery when trying to put it back to win 8.

The recovery didn't finish and now nothing will boot. It goes into the recovery environment at boot but every single option I click gives me an error. This might even be the win 10 recovery environment instead of the win 8 one.

Does anyone know how to recover either of the windows without a boot disc/flash drive?

All I have are cd-rws and no dvds and i keep reading that dvds are needed for the iso. I'd rather just see if there's a way to recover without the dvds/flash drive. Please let me know either way and what I should do.

Comment: In order to do what you want.  You will need to download a Windows 8.1 ISO, boot to WinPE, then install Windows 8.1.  Your recovery partition was likely updated when you upgraded to Windows 10 originally.  Due to your actions this cannot be solved without a Windows 8.1 installation disk

Comment: how do i get the ISO to that computer? I am not on the computer that can't boot into windows, i'm on my laptop. I don't have dvds or flash drive, just cd-rws

Comment: You need to get a flash storage device.  How you download a Windows 8.1 is well documented.  What part of that process are you stuck on

Answer (score -1):

If it is OEM version – system pre-install with hardware, you can consider of restore system back to factory setting. You can contact the hardware provider/office supporter, confirm with them if they can help you to re-set the system.

> The recovery didn't finish and now nothing will boot. It goes into the recovery environment at boot but every single option I click gives me an error.

If you can open CMD, try to use “***sfc /scannow***” to check/repair system files.

Article “**Use Bootrec.exe in the Windows RE to troubleshoot startup issues**” can also be considered as a reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues

If problem persists, as you are unable to boot into system and reparation option prompts error, then, install medium might be necessary to boot into system to d reparation/re-installation.